# Show $a_n=\frac{3^n}{n!}$ is decreasing and bounded below

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show $a_n=\frac{3^n}{n!}$ is decreasing and bounded below.

I tried with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, but it only got me $\frac{3}{n+1}$ after cancel out everything and I can't determine this to be less than 1, never to say the bounded below part.

Comment: The bounded below part is very easy, all the numbers are $\ge 0$, or, if you want a sillier (but correct) lower bound, all the numbers are $\ge -42$.

Comment: For bounded below: show it it positive, so bounded below by zero.  For decreasing: compute the first few terms, to see that "decreasong" only starts at some point later than the beginning.

Comment: It is not, technically, decreasing, only "eventually" decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you showed that the ratio is $\frac{3}{n + 1}$, note that this is at most $1$ for all $n \ge 2$. It's worth mentioning that the sequence is only decreasing for $n \ge 2$, since $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = 4.5$, $a_3 = 4.5$ and $a_4 = 3.375$.

---

As far as a lower bound, notice every term is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\geq 2$. By induction,  $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{3^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\frac{3^n}{n!}=\frac{3}{n+1}a_n-\frac{3}{n}a_{n-1}\leq \frac{3}{n}(a_{n}-a_{n-1})\leq 0.$$